# Exclude null or zeroes in previous trading days average calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I thought I got it, but actually not. Working with some trading data and need to do average stockprice for trading days only. Used the below query for 3 day average; but recently found out there can be dividends on a trading holiday; so for those days in the fact table there is data for the stockcode and closeprice is either zero or null.

Please help me to improve my query to ignore zero and nulls in the 3 preceding trading day's average calculation

```
select StockCode, datekey, ClosePrice, 
AVG(ClosePrice) OVER (partition by StockCode order by datekey 
ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) Avg3Days
from Fact
```

Comment: How can you distinguish trading days and non-trading days in the data?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Are you looking for day weighting ?

Comment: When you say ignore, do you mean at if "day 2" is `NULL`, then you want `(day1 + day3) / 2` or end up with `(day1 + day3 + day4) / 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partition by `StockCode` AND `sign(NullIf([ClosePrice],0))` rather than having to know the trading days.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([datekey] date,[StockCode] varchar(50),[ClosePrice] money)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2019-06-15','xyx',5)
,('2019-06-16','xyx',10)
,('2019-06-17','xyx',NULL)
,('2019-06-18','xyx',0)
,('2019-06-19','xyx',15)
,('2019-06-20','xyx',20)

Select * 
     ,AvgPrice = AVG(ClosePrice) over (partition by StockCode,sign(NullIf([ClosePrice],0)) order By datekey rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding  )      
from @YourTable
Order By datekey
```

**Returns**

```
datekey     StockCode   ClosePrice  AvgPrice
2019-06-15  xyx         5.00        NULL
2019-06-16  xyx         10.00       5.00
2019-06-17  xyx         NULL        NULL
2019-06-18  xyx         0.00        NULL
2019-06-19  xyx         15.00       7.50
2019-06-20  xyx         20.00       10.00
```

**Update**

A little uglier, but perhaps something like this

```
Select * 
     ,AvgPrice = case when sum(1)          over (partition by StockCode,sign(NullIf([ClosePrice],0)) order By datekey rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding  ) = 3
                      then avg(ClosePrice) over (partition by StockCode,sign(NullIf([ClosePrice],0)) order By datekey rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding  )      
                      else null end
from @YourTable
Order By datekey
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: This is AWESOME!! Thank you for this piece of code. I am accepting this as solution. Is there a way AvgPrice from 2019-06-15 to 2019-06-19 be shown as NULL or 0 as it is incorrect till we get 3 real values. In my real case I make 30, 45 and 60 day averages. So basically for first ~3 months (including holidays) the average is wrong.

Comment: @ITNube  Happy it helped.  Take a peek at the UPDTE

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a flag that indicates trading days, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT StockCode, datekey, ClosePrice, 
       (CASE WHEN isTradingDay = 1
             THEN AVG(ClosePrice) OVER (PARTITION BY StockCode, isTradingDay
                                        ORDER BY datekey 
                                        ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                                       )
        END) as Avg3Days
FROM Fact;
```

This takes the average of the previous three trading days.  The value is `NULL` on non-trading days.

If the `StockCode` is `NULL`, it will not be included in the average anyway.  If the only indicator is the `closePrice`, then one method is:

```
SELECT f.StockCode, f.datekey, f.ClosePrice, 
       (CASE WHEN v.isTradingDay = 1
             THEN AVG(f.ClosePrice) OVER (PARTITION BY f.StockCode, v.isTradingDay
                                          ORDER BY f.datekey 
                                          ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                                         )
        END) as Avg3Days
FROM Fact f CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN f.ClosePrice > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     ) v(isTradingDay);
```

Personally, I would prefer to have an explicit trading day indicator rather than relying on special values of the close price.  For instance, trading on a single stock might be suspending for some company-specific reason.

You may want to also have `WHERE f.StockCode <> ''` to filter out invalid stock codes.